# LTspice UVLO excercise

Tags: ltspice

[image]

[image]
[image]

How do I properly set this up in LTspice to determine Vin during rising and falling? I kind of a loss on how to answer this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to ditch the simulator and calculate this by hand. Or is this for a class about simulators?

Comment: can you give me a hint on how to do it by hand thank you!

Comment: by connected to Vulvo do you mean in parallel to R2?

Comment: Basically, yes. Not sure about the direction though. For an ideal current source like this it actually doesn't matter where the other side is connected. (I mean, changing between parallel to R1 vs parallel to R2 is equivalent to having the current be negative). I've converted my comments to an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the two cases separately.

The "Vin falling" case will just be a simple resistive voltage divider. Given \$V_{uvlo} = 1.22\text{V}\$, can you solve for \$V_{in}\$?

The "Vin rising" case will have the current source connected to \$V_{uvlo}\$. The question doesn't specify whether current should be going into or out from the node. You should be able to solve this case using KCL. I suggest you solve for both cases (current in and current out) and see which one causes the circuit to have the right type of hysteresis. Have you learned what hysteresis is?

Comment: 1.22 = 0.5Vin hence Vin = 2.44V is this correct?

Comment: Do I still have to use the 1.22V in the Vin rising case?

Comment: @Paumdrdo - Yes, still 1.22V for \$V_{uvlo}\$ for the rising case. Solve the KCL equation for the node.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this should be done manually, which is quite straightforward, however Here is a simulation using LTspice:

[image]

The behavioral current source equation

> I = 2.5E-6*(0.5 + 0.5*tanh( 100*(1.22-V(V_control) )))

simply provides a current source of 2.5uA if the voltage at V_control is < 1.22V and 0uA if it is greater than 1.22V. The hyperbolic tangent function provides a 'smooth' output that is differentiable.